# creating my own virtualwrapper template

Tags: virtualenvwrapper

If i'm reading the documentation on [virtualenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/docs/virtualenvwrapper/index.html) correctly then i should be able to create my own templates. Which will be useful for managing several different types of projects.

Flask on github
vs say
django on bitbucket

Unfortunately i don't see any clear documentation on how this achieved (though to more experienced eyes it might be rather clear)

Its also possible that i'm missing the larger picture.

Any suggestions?